# look for file of a certain type one subfolder down, sort by date modified (newest first), and display subfolder name (NOT filename) in sorted order

Tags: sorting, batch-file

This is a very specific question, so I've separated it into 3 parts.

1. Look in all subfolders for a certain file: `world.sav`, but only 1 level down, i.e.

   ```
   C:\workingdir\foo\world.sav
   C:\workingdir\bar\world.sav
   C:\workingdir\baz\world.sav
   C:\workingdir\qux\world.sav
   ```

   is fine, but

   ```
   C:\workingdir\foo\bar\world.sav
   C:\workingdir\world.sav
   ```

   isn't, etc.
2. Sort these `world.sav` files by date modified (newest first).
3. Display the name of the subfolder each `world.sav` file is in, in the previously sorted order. i.e. if the above list was date-sorted into

   ```
   C:\workingdir\qux\world.sav (newest)
   C:\workingdir\bar\world.sav
   C:\workingdir\foo\world.sav
   C:\workingdir\baz\world.sav (oldest)
   ```

   then the output would be

   ```
   qux
   bar
   foo
   baz
   ```

   I've tried numerous methods involving `DIR`, `FORFILES` and manipulation of variables, but the 2 main problems I've come across so far are

   - Both commands mentioned above will arrange by subfolder, then by date, and I can't find a way to avoid it.
   - Date formatting. It appears to be different for every localization of Windows, and I really want this to be locale-independent.

Also, it must support spaces in folder names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED version with a wait message:**

```
@echo off
echo Please wait... 
cd /d "c:\workingdir" 
(for /d %%a in (*) do @robocopy "%%a" "%%a" world.sav /L /nocopy /is /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /ts)|(
   @cls
   for /f "tokens=2*" %%b in ('sort /r') do @for %%z in ("%%~dpc\.") do @echo %%~nz
)
cd /d "%~dp0"
echo.
pause
```

**original version below**

This works here:

`robocopy` is used on each folder in the directory to generate a list (`UTCdate time drv:\path\world.sav` format) and that is sorted to get most recent at the top of the list, which the second `for` parses to extract the `drv:\path\folder\world.sav` and the last `for` loop prints out just the `folder` name.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\workingdir"
(for /d %%a in (*) do @robocopy "%%a" "%%a" world.sav /L /nocopy /is /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /ts)|for /f "tokens=2*" %%b in ('sort /r') do @for %%z in ("%%~dpc\.") do @echo %%~nz
pause
```

Comment: doesn't seem to support folders with spaces

Comment: It does now.  I tested it with your samples so I didn't notice the discrepancy. :)

Comment: much shorter and faster to run than the other two methods. thanks.

Comment: so, i have an edited version, which basically adds a "please wait" message:


`echo Please wait...


cd /d "c:\workingdir"


(for /d %%a in (*) do @robocopy "%%a" "%%a" world.sav /L /nocopy /is /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /ts)|for /f "tokens=2*" %%b in ('sort /r') do @for %%z in ("%%~dpc\.") do @echo %%~nz>>temp_file.txt


CLS&TYPE TEMP_FILE.TXT


del /q TEMP_FILE.TXT


CD %~dp0


echo.


pause`


is there a way to not use a temp file?

Answer (score 0):

An idea :

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set $WorkDir="C:\eh\guh\blugh\fneh\mork\workingdir"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s/b/a-d %$WorkDir%') do (
 for /f "tokens=9 delims=\" %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
  if /i "%%b"=="world.sav" call:next "%%~pa" %%~ta
)
)
::Resultat
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%r in ('set #') do echo %%r
exit/b

:next
for /f "tokens=7 delims=\" %%c in ('echo %~1') do set $Path=%%c
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%c in ('echo %~2') do set #%%e%%d%%c=!$path!
```

Comment: "Environment variable # not defined"

Comment: check the EDIT : Is your paths like this exactly C:\workingdir\qux\world.sav

Comment: there are 8 \s in my path, so would that mean i'd change it to 9?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly 9 !

Comment: OK check my new EDIT. I adapted it with your PATH.

Comment: ok, it works if i change the first tokens value to 8 instead, but only with the folders that don't have spaces.

Comment: Corrected for the path with space

Comment: this works now, although foxidrive's answer is better. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET /a count=0
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO IF exist "%sourcedir%\%%a\world.sav" CALL :set$ "%%a"

IF %count%==0 ECHO No files found&GOTO :EOF
IF %count%==1 ECHO %$1%&GOTO :EOF
:sortol
SET /a start=1
SET /a swap=0
:sortil
CALL :compdt
IF %start% neq %count% GOTO sortil
IF %swap% neq 0 GOTO sortol
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,%count%) DO CALL ECHO %%$%%a%%
GOTO :EOF

:set$
SET /a count+=1
SET "$%count%=%~1"
GOTO :eof

:compdt
CALL SET f1=%%$%start%%%
SET /a START +=1
CALL SET f2=%%$%start%%%
FOR /f %%a IN (
  'echo f^|xcopy /L /y /d "%sourcedir%\%f1%\world.sav" "%sourcedir%\%f2%\world.sav"'
 ) DO SET copies=%%a
IF %copies%==0 GOTO :EOF
SET /a swap +=1
SET /a START -=1
SET "$%start%=%f2%"
SET /a START +=1
SET "$%start%=%f1%"
GOTO :eof
```

This worked for me. You'd need to set `sourcedir` to suit your purpose.

Essentially, it builds a list of the next-level-down directory names which contain the target filename in variables `$1`...`$whatever`, then sorts the names using a simple bubble-sort which relies on the characteristics of `xcopy`. `XCOPY`'s `/L` switch simply lists the files that would be copied; `/y` tells it to 'go ahead (and not copy)' and `/d` says 'only later files`.`ECHO`ing`f`tells`xcopy`that the desired "copy" is a file-copy, so it responds`1 file(s) copied`or`0...` as its last line, depending on whether the source file was later than the destination.

To reverse the order, simply change the `if %copies%==0` to `if %copies%==1`

Comment: runs extremely slowly on my pc.